# Using logging abstractions in class library without DI

Tags: c#, logging

I have a C# .NET 7 library, initialized by other WPF/console applications with extension method. Library doesn't link to any external logging providers, but must use the one, granted by main application. In library services (like MyLibService1, MyLibService2) dependency injection with `ILogger<>` works fine. The problem is with logging in extension method.

Here is library simplified initialization code:

```
public static class AddMyLibraryExtensions
{
    public static HostApplicationBuilder AddMyLibrary(this HostApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var libConfiguration = builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection("MyLibrary");

        builder.Services.AddOptions<MyLibrarySettings>()
            .Bind(libConfiguration);
        
        builder.Services.TryAddTransient<IMyLibService1, MyLibService1>();
        builder.Services.TryAddTransient<IMyLibService2, MyLibService2>();

        var libSettings = libConfiguration.Get<MyLibrarySettings>();

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyLibDbContext>(opts =>
        {
            opts.UseSqlite(libSettings.ConnectionString);
        });
        
        return builder;
    }
}
```

And it is used in application in this way (CreateApplicationBuilder() have many benefits, so it is used here):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IAppService1, AppService1>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IAppService2, AppService2>();

        builder.AddMyLibrary(); // My library may be added here...

        builder.Services.AddLogging(cfg =>
        {
            var logConf = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
                .CreateLogger();

            Log.Logger = logConf;

            cfg.AddSerilog(logConf); // for example Serilog
        });

        // builder.AddLibrary(); // or here...
        var host = builder.Build();

        var job = host.Services.GetService<IAppService1>();
        job.DoWork();
}
```

So, library doesn't know - when logging will be added (if any), what provider, and in it's extension method it can't use dependency injection, and, before host is build it can't use host's ServiceLocator

Are there any ways to use application logging (if any) in AddMyLibrary method ?

Currently I see one - send application logger as parameter to extension method, like .AddMyLibrary(object logger).
Bit it's ugly ...

Comment: Allow you library to accept an `ILogger` interface in its constructor. If Serilog (or any other logger) is registered to resolve a logger when it sees `ILogger`, then it will inject it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> like .AddMyLibrary(object logger).

There is not much what can be done here. If for whatever reason you want to log during the registration you will need to explicitly ask for a logger to be provided. So just add [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) parameter to the method and use it:

```
public static HostApplicationBuilder AddMyLibrary(this HostApplicationBuilder builder, ILogger logger)
{
    logger.Log(...);
}
```

And then for Serilog you can use the [`Serilog.Extensions.Logging`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/tree/dev) to adapt the logger to Microsoft provided interface (for example via [`SerilogLoggerProvider`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/Extensions/Logging/SerilogLoggerProvider.cs)).

P.S.

Also personally when creating such extension methods I tend to provide the ability to override the configuration section used, for example:

```
public static HostApplicationBuilder AddMyLibrary(this HostApplicationBuilder builder, string cfgSectionPath = "MyLibrary")
{
    builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection(cfgSectionPath);
}
```

Or even just request for the settings (i.e. `MyLibrarySettings`) as explicit parameter.

Comment: I follow your advice, so .AddMyLibrary signature became:
public static HostApplicationBuilder AddMyLibrary(
    this HostApplicationBuilder builder,
    ILogger? logger = null,
    string configSectionPath = MyLibrarySettings.SectionName)